# Get country from curl request using php

Tags: php, html, curl

I am working on apps where i try to use curl.Before that  i try to use `file_get_contents()` but that was not working on my server due to `allow_url` issue ( i tried to contact hosting but not resolve yet so i try alternate ).So i used curl to get data from remote site.I get data using this code :

```
$url="http://api.hostip.info/get_html.php?ip=182.188.193.238";
$ch = curl_init();
// Disable SSL verification
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
// Will return the response, if false it print the response
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
// Set the url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
// Execute
$result=curl_exec($ch);
// Closing
curl_close($ch);

print_r($result);
```

when i print i get `Country: PAKISTAN (PK) City: Lahore IP: 182.188.193.238`.I want to get the country from this string.I tried like this but get empty result like `$data = json_decode($result,true);` . Json decode returns empty result.I think only way is to break that string ? Thanks for any hints in advance.I want to get the country name from the result.

Comment: That's not JSON. So you have to use `preg_match()` with a regex to get that out of the response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `preg_match`

```
preg_match('/Country: (?P<country>\w+)/', $result, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Country: PAKISTAN 
    [country] => PAKISTAN
    [1] => PAKISTAN
)
```

So you would get country name with

```
$countryName = $matches['country'];
```

As @hardik solanki said, there is also JSON endpoint `get_json.php`.

```
$url = "http://api.hostip.info/get_json.php?ip=182.188.193.238";
```

To get country from JSON response, use this:

```
$response = json_decode($result);
$countryName = $response->country_name;
```

Comment: I think this is the fastest way if the OP just want the country.

Answer (score 4):

As per API doc, You can get also json response using `get_json.php`

Just used `get_json.php` instead of `get_html.php`.

Your code should be :

```
$url="http://api.hostip.info/get_json.php?ip=182.188.193.238";
$ch = curl_init();
// Disable SSL verification
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
// Will return the response, if false it print the response
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
// Set the url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
// Execute
$result=curl_exec($ch);
// Closing
curl_close($ch);
$data = json_decode($result,true);
print_r($data);
```

Comment: Nice one. I think this is the cleanest solution :-).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind, use get_content

```
$content = get_content("http://api.hostip.info/get_html.php?ip=182.188.193.238");

$country = stristr($content, 'Country: ');

$country = stristr($country, 'City:', true);

$country= ucfirst(str_replace('Country: ', '', $country));

echo $country;
```